# How to read the first 31 rows and take the third element of each row C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, readfile

I have to read two files which are distributed differently. I also need to do a comparison if the first element is the same as the second. No number but simply whether № of station in one file is the same as № station in another file (the first element of the two files), then I need to compare the years that start and end of the same year.
Then you need to charge in combobox1 № of station and combobox2 years from beginning to end of the first file.
Then I need to read 31 lines for the selected year from first file.

I do not know why combobox2 fill only one year rather than all the years.

I create class DataEntry:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class DataEntry
    {



        public string Station { get; set; }


        //2. item
        public string Year
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //3. item
        public string Number
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //4. item
        public string January
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //5. item
        public string February
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //6. item
        public string March
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //7. item
        public string April
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //8. item
        public string Mai
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //9. item
        public string Juni
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //10. item
        public string Juli
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //11. item
        public string August
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //12. item
        public string September
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //13. item
        public string October
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //14. item
        public string November
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //15. item
        public string December
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

After create second class: DataFile

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class DataFile
    {

        public DataFile()
        {
            this.Entries = new List<DataEntry>();
        }


        public List<DataEntry> Entries { get; }



        public static DataFile Load(string[] allLines)
        {
            DataFile result = new DataFile();

            //  if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
            //  {
            //      string[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

            DataEntry entry = new DataEntry();

            foreach (var line in allLines)
                {
                    var splittedValues = line.Split(',');


                    entry.Station = splittedValues[0];
                    entry.Year = splittedValues[1];
                    entry.Number = splittedValues[2];
                    entry.January = splittedValues[3];
                    entry.February = splittedValues[4];
                    entry.March = splittedValues[5];
                    entry.April = splittedValues[6];
                    entry.Mai = splittedValues[7];
                    entry.Juni = splittedValues[8];
                    entry.Juli = splittedValues[9];
                    entry.August = splittedValues[10];
                    entry.September = splittedValues[11];
                    entry.October = splittedValues[12];
                    entry.November = splittedValues[13];
                    entry.December = splittedValues[14];
                }

            result.Entries.Add(entry);
           // }

            return result;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if all entries (all lines of the csv file) have the same station (the same first word).
        /// If one entry have another first word it returns false.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool CheckStation()
        {
            string station = string.Empty;
            bool firstEntry = true;

            foreach (var entry in this.Entries)
            {
                if (firstEntry)
                {
                    station = entry.Station;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (entry.Station != station)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the entries of the file which have the same year as given.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="year"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public DataEntry[] GetAllEntriesOfOneYear(string year)
        {
            return this.Entries.Where(p => p.Year == year).ToArray();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if this entries contains the same years as the entries of the given file
        /// If one file have one more or less year it returns false
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="otherFile"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool CheckYears(DataFile otherFile)
        {

            return true;
            string[] allPossibleYearsOfThisFile = this.GetYears();
            string[] allPossibleYearsOfTheOtherFile = otherFile.GetYears();

            if (allPossibleYearsOfThisFile.Length != allPossibleYearsOfTheOtherFile.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var year in allPossibleYearsOfThisFile)
                {
                    if (!allPossibleYearsOfTheOtherFile.Contains(year))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns all possible years of the entries.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string[] GetYears()
        {
           // string[] years = new string[9999];
           //
           // foreach (var item in Entries)
           // {
           //     years = item.Year;
           // }
           // return years;

            return this.Entries.Select(p => p.Year).Distinct().ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Create third class Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class Service
    {
        internal string[] GetAllYears(DataFile firstFile)
        {
       //     DataFile rstFile = firstFile;

            return firstFile.Entries.Select(p => p.Year).Distinct().ToArray();

        }
    }
}
```

Code in the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

       private Service service;

        DataFile firstFile;
        DataFile secondFile;

        public Form1()
        {
            service = new Service();
         //   firstFile = new DataFile();
          //  secondFile = new DataFile();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private SQLiteConnection Connection;



        string pathFolder;
        string pathFolder2;

        List<string> resultYears = new List<string>();
        List<string> resultYears2 = new List<string>();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string sFileName = dialog.FileName;
                    pathFolder = sFileName;

                    label3.Text = pathFolder;
                    label3.Show();
                    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName);

                    firstFile = DataFile.Load(lines);

                    if (!firstFile.CheckStation())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Файла с дневни данни трябва да съдържа само една станция!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string sFileName = dialog.FileName;
                    pathFolder2 = sFileName;

                    label4.Text = pathFolder2;
                    label4.Show();

                    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName);

                    secondFile = DataFile.Load(lines);

                    if (!secondFile.CheckStation())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Файла с месечни данни трябва съдържа само една станция!");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (firstFile != null && secondFile != null)
            {
                if (firstFile.Entries.FirstOrDefault().Station.ToString() != secondFile.Entries.FirstOrDefault().Station.ToString())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Номера на станцията в единия файл не отговаря на номера на станцията в другият файл!" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                        "ЗАБЕЛЕЖКА!" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "В двата файла, номера на станцията трябва да бъде един и същ!");
                }

                comboBox1.Items.Add(firstFile.Entries.First().Station);

                List<string> years = new List<string>();



                //  if (firstFile.CheckYears(secondFile))
                //  {

                comboBox2.Items.AddRange(service.GetAllYears(firstFile));


                //comboBox2.Items.Add(firstFile.GetYears());
             //  }
              // else
              // {
              //     MessageBox.Show("Годините от двата файла не съвпадат.");
              // }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("One or both files are empty. Please select the file and read the data first.");
            }
        }


        public void loadEntries()
        {
            string selectedYear = this.comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();

            DataEntry[] entries = firstFile.GetAllEntriesOfOneYear(selectedYear);

            //TODO:
            //Now you have all lines of the first file which have the selected year.
            //With this list you can work
        }

        public void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Really I Dont know why combobox2 not fill with all years, only with the 2015 (last year).

First CSV file:

```
    18050,1976,1,0.390,0.660,0.290,0.740,9.160,1.400,0.670,3.120,0.460,0.420,0.360,0.400,
18050,1976,2,0.390,0.520,0.290,0.740,7.540,1.270,0.670,2.660,0.460,0.420,0.360,0.380,
18050,1976,3,0.390,0.450,0.240,0.660,5.260,1.270,0.670,2.510,0.460,0.420,0.410,0.400,
18050,1976,4,0.390,0.450,0.240,0.660,4.400,1.180,0.620,2.360,0.460,0.410,0.400,0.440,
18050,1976,5,0.390,0.450,0.290,0.660,4.220,1.080,0.620,2.360,0.460,0.410,0.400,4.750,
18050,1976,6,0.520,0.390,0.240,0.580,4.040,1.270,0.620,4.200,0.460,0.410,0.380,2.810,
18050,1976,7,0.390,0.390,0.240,0.520,3.680,37.800,0.620,5.870,0.460,0.400,0.360,1.620,
18050,1976,8,0.390,0.390,0.200,0.580,3.330,22.900,0.580,4.570,0.460,0.380,0.360,0.980,
18050,1976,9,0.390,0.390,0.200,0.660,2.830,11.200,0.580,4.020,0.460,0.360,0.360,0.740,
18050,1976,10,0.390,0.340,0.200,1.380,2.650,8.120,0.580,3.660,0.440,0.360,0.360,0.520,
18050,1976,11,0.340,0.390,0.200,2.260,2.350,5.870,0.580,3.270,0.440,0.360,0.360,0.460,
18050,1976,12,0.340,0.450,0.200,1.700,2.350,4.750,0.580,4.570,0.440,0.360,0.360,0.460,
18050,1976,13,0.340,0.390,0.200,1.590,2.350,3.840,0.540,4.020,0.440,0.340,0.360,0.440,
18050,1976,14,0.340,0.390,0.290,2.120,2.200,3.120,0.540,3.660,0.420,0.340,0.340,0.520,
18050,1976,15,0.290,0.390,0.290,2.400,2.050,2.970,0.540,3.270,0.420,0.400,0.340,0.520,
18050,1976,16,0.290,0.390,0.240,1.590,1.770,2.810,0.540,2.970,0.420,0.360,0.340,0.440,
18050,1976,17,0.290,0.340,0.290,1.170,1.520,2.660,0.540,2.660,0.410,0.360,0.330,0.420,
18050,1976,18,0.290,0.340,0.290,1.170,1.270,2.360,0.540,2.210,0.410,0.410,0.340,0.420,
18050,1976,19,0.240,0.340,0.390,1.170,1.080,2.210,0.540,2.060,0.410,0.410,0.400,0.410,
18050,1976,20,0.290,0.340,0.390,1.010,1.080,2.060,0.520,1.760,0.400,0.400,1.340,0.400,
18050,1976,21,0.290,0.290,0.390,0.920,1.270,1.760,0.520,1.200,0.740,0.400,2.660,0.400,
18050,1976,22,0.340,0.290,0.450,0.820,2.860,1.480,0.520,1.080,0.580,0.380,1.760,0.400,
18050,1976,23,0.340,0.290,0.520,0.740,3.050,1.200,0.520,0.980,0.580,0.380,0.980,0.400,
18050,1976,24,0.340,0.290,0.520,0.660,4.000,0.980,0.540,0.810,0.540,0.380,0.520,0.380,
18050,1976,25,0.340,0.290,0.920,0.740,2.680,0.890,2.810,0.670,0.520,0.360,0.460,0.380,
18050,1976,26,0.390,0.290,1.380,1.380,2.060,0.810,2.510,0.580,0.520,0.360,0.440,0.380,
18050,1976,27,0.740,0.290,1.490,2.570,1.770,0.810,2.510,0.580,0.490,0.360,0.420,0.380,
18050,1976,28,1.280,0.290,1.380,2.730,1.770,0.740,4.750,0.520,0.460,0.360,0.410,0.360,
18050,1976,29,1.010,0.290,1.090,3.610,1.650,0.740,5.480,0.520,0.420,0.360,0.410,0.360,
18050,1976,30,0.820,,0.820,4.000,1.520,0.670,4.210,0.490,0.420,0.360,0.400,0.360,
18050,1976,31,0.660,,0.740,,1.520,,3.660,0.460,,0.360,,0.440,
```

Down goes the same way with the subsequent year until 2015

Second CSV file:

```
    18050,1976,НМ,0.240,0.240,0.160,0.520,0.990,0.670,0.490,0.460,0.400,0.340,0.330,0.360,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1976,СР,0.440,0.370,0.480,1.380,2.880,4.340,1.280,2.380,0.470,0.380,0.560,0.700,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1976,НГ,1.380,0.660,1.560,4.640,9.800,53.500,6.270,6.270,0.810,0.420,2.810,5.300,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1976,,,,НМ,0.160,СР,1.310,НГ,53.500,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1977,НМ,0.320,1.030,0.540,0.360,0.240,0.360,0.340,0.120,0.100,0.140,0.120,0.140,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1977,СР,0.620,1.720,1.430,0.530,0.400,0.800,0.470,0.230,0.230,0.170,0.260,0.260,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1977,НГ,3.860,7.040,4.300,1.140,2.050,8.500,1.030,0.360,2.050,0.360,2.050,1.770,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1977,,,,НМ,0.100,СР,0.590,НГ,8.500,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1978,НМ,0.140,0.200,0.200,0.670,0.580,0.160,0.140,0.120,0.140,0.092,0.110,0.200,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1978,СР,0.250,0.420,0.720,1.090,0.710,0.370,0.250,0.200,0.240,0.170,0.130,0.630,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1978,НГ,1.260,3.140,5.340,2.950,1.480,0.770,0.510,0.510,1.070,0.270,0.300,3.450,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1978,,,,НМ,0.092,СР,0.430,НГ,5.340,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1979,НМ,0.090,0.209,0.175,0.175,0.580,0.540,0.485,0.433,0.171,0.120,0.150,0.210,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1979,СР,0.522,0.533,0.274,2.373,3.058,0.978,0.654,0.680,0.365,0.241,0.364,0.302,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1979,НГ,3.100,1.733,0.562,14.250,10.820,3.351,1.530,2.100,1.366,1.066,1.170,0.700,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
18050,1979,,,,НМ,0.090,СР,0.863,НГ,14.250,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

НГ means the max values
CP represents the avg value
NM means the min value

Comment: Show us your code and where it fails.

Comment: Look at http://filehelpers.net

Comment: By using a `StreamReader` you can read a file line by line. A simple separation can be done by using `String.Split()` from where you could take the first element.

Comment: I, update my post

Comment: Even with the code, it is unclear what you mean that "it doesn't work."  What, *exactly*, doesn't work?

Comment: Your first mistake is using `String.Split(',')`; that does not work. You second mistake is trying to do this yourself instead of using a packages like [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.net/) that already does this correctly.

Comment: I fix my code. Now he works by taking the first word of each line read two files and compares whether the first elements are the same. But it was time to take the second element off the file (that year) and should add them in a combobox.
For now I managed to take only the second element of the first line. I want to take the second element of each line so I can compare them and adds them to the combobox.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use something like this to get the First word from each line of a file;

```
string pathToFile = "Your path here";
char delimiter = ' ';// You have to use ',' if you need to split with ,
List<string> firstWordList =  File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile).Select(x => x.Split(delimiter).First()).ToList();
```

Where,

- `File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile)` will gives you the Lines in the file as a collection
- `.Select(x => x.Split(delimiter)` will help you to iterate through the collection and select items based on the `split` results
- `x.Split(delimiter).First()`, `Split` will help you to split each item in the list based on the delimiter and the `first()` will help you to take the first among the splitted values. So finally the variable `firstWordList` will contains the required List of words

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to compare two files. The first word in each row is the name of the sender. There should be only one name per file and each row should begin with the same name.

You read the lines of your file but compare the first found name always to itself. You forgot to use the name of the current row.

Try this

```
using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string sFileName = dialog.FileName;
        pathFolder2 = sFileName;
        label3.Text = pathFolder2;
        label3.Show();

        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName);

        int i = 0;

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var splittedValues = line.Split(',');

            var firstWord = splittedValues[0];

            if (i == 0)
            {
                resultStation2 = firstWord;
            }
            else
            {
                if (resultStation2 != firstWord)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Файла трябва да съдържа само една станция!");
                    return;
                }
            }

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the line `result.Add(splittedValues[0]);` to `var firstWord = splittedValues[0];` and used the variable `firstWord` instead of `result[0]`.

**Update**
If you want all years of each line in the file you have to use a list of years.

Variable Declaration:
(You should initialize the lists in the constructor of the form)

```
List<string> resultYears; //string resultYear;
List<string> resultYears2; //string resultYear2;
```

Read the file:

```
var year = splittedValues[1];

resultYears.Add(year);
```

Compare the files:

```
if (resultStation != resultStation2)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Номера на станцията в единия файл не отговаря на номера на станцията в другият файл!" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                "ЗАБЕЛЕЖКА!" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "В двата файла, номера на станцията трябва да бъде един и същ!");
}

comboBox1.Items.Add(resultStation);

for (int i = 0; i < (this.resultYears.Count > this.resultYears2.Count ? this.resultYears.Count : this.resultYears2.Count); i++)
{
    var year = i < this.resultYears.Count ? this.resultYears[i] : string.Empty;
    var year2 = i < this.resultYears2.Count ? this.resultYears2[i] : string.Empty;

    if (year == year2)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(year);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Годините от двата файла не съвпадат.");
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

I helped you with the objectModel.

Create a class DataEntry:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DemoProject
{
    public class DataEntry
    {
        public DataEntry()
        {

        }

        //1. item
        public string Station
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //2. item
        public string Year
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //3. item
        public string Number
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //4. item
        public string January
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //5. item
        public string February
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //6. item
        public string March
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //7. item
        public string April
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //8. item
        public string Mai
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //9. item
        public string Juni
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //10. item
        public string Juli
        {
            get;
            set;
        }    

        //11. item
        public string August
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //12. item
        public string September
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //13. item
        public string October
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //14. item
        public string November
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //15. item
        public string December
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Create a second class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DemoProject
{
    public class DataFile
    {
        public DataFile()
        {
            this.Entries = new List<DataEntry>();
        }

        public List<DataEntry> Entries
        {
            get;
        }

        public static DataFile Load(string fileName)
        {
            DataFile result = new DataFile();

            if(System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                string[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

                foreach (var line in allLines)
                {
                    var splittedValues = line.Split(',');

                    DataEntry entry = new DataEntry();

                    entry.Station = splittedValues[0];
                    entry.Year = splittedValues[1];
                    entry.Number = splittedValues[2];
                    entry.January = splittedValues[3];
                    entry.February = splittedValues[4];
                    entry.March = splittedValues[5];
                    entry.April = splittedValues[6];
                    entry.Mai = splittedValues[7];
                    entry.Juni = splittedValues[8];
                    entry.Juli = splittedValues[9];
                    entry.August = splittedValues[10];
                    entry.September = splittedValues[11];
                    entry.October = splittedValues[12];
                    entry.November = splittedValues[13];
                    entry.December = splittedValues[14];
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if all entries (all lines of the csv file) have the same station (the same first word).
        /// If one entry have another first word it returns false.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool CheckStation()
        {
            string station = string.Empty;
            bool firstEntry = true;

            foreach (var entry in this.Entries)
            {
                if(firstEntry)
                {
                    station = entry.Station;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(entry.Station != station)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the entries of the file which have the same year as given.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="year"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public DataEntry[] GetAllEntriesOfOneYear(string year)
        {
            return this.Entries.Where(p => p.Year == year).ToArray();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if this entries contains the same years as the entries of the given file
        /// If one file have one more or less year it returns false
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="otherFile"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool CheckYears(DataFile otherFile)
        {
            string[] allPossibleYearsOfThisFile = this.GetYears();
            string[] allPossibleYearsOfTheOtherFile = otherFile.GetYears();

            if(allPossibleYearsOfThisFile.Length != allPossibleYearsOfTheOtherFile.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var year in allPossibleYearsOfThisFile)
                {
                    if(!allPossibleYearsOfTheOtherFile.Contains(year))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns all possible years of the entries.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string[] GetYears()
        {
            return this.Entries.Select(p => p.Year).Distinct().ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Update your code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DemoProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataFile firstFile;
        DataFile secondFile;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string sFileName = dialog.FileName;
                    pathFolder = sFileName;

                    label3.Text = pathFolder;
                    label3.Show();

                    firstFile = DataFile.Load(dialog.FileName);

                    if(firstFile.CheckStation())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Файла с дневни данни трябва да съдържа само една станция!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string sFileName = dialog.FileName;
                    pathFolder2 = sFileName;

                    label4.Text = pathFolder2;
                    label4.Show();

                    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName);

                    int i = 0;

                    secondFile = DataFile.Load(dialog.FileName);

                    if (secondFile.CheckStation())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Файла с месечни данни трябва съдържа само една станция!");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (firstFile != null && secondFile != null)
            {
                if (firstFile.Entries.First().Station != secondFile.Entries.First().Station)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Номера на станцията в единия файл не отговаря на номера на станцията в другият файл!" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                        "ЗАБЕЛЕЖКА!" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "В двата файла, номера на станцията трябва да бъде един и същ!");
                }

                comboBox1.Items.Add(firstFile.Entries.First().Station);

                if (firstFile.CheckYears(secondFile))
                {
                    comboBox2.Items.AddRange(firstFile.GetYears());
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Годините от двата файла не съвпадат.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("One or both files are empty. Please select the file and read the data first.");
            }
        }

        public void loadEntries()
        {
            string selectedYear = this.comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();

            DataEntry[] entries = firstFile.GetAllEntriesOfOneYear(selectedYear);

            //TODO:
            //Now you have all lines of the first file which have the selected year.
            //With this list you can work
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I found your problem. The load method of your DataFile-class is not correct.
You create on object and then loop over all lines. You always change the values of this one object but not create for each line an own object. It shows only one year because it have only one year.

The corrected load method is

```
public static DataFile Load(string[] allLines)
{
    DataFile result = new DataFile();

    foreach (var line in allLines)
    {
        DataEntry entry = new DataEntry();

        var splittedValues = line.Split(',');

        entry.Station = splittedValues[0];
        entry.Year = splittedValues[1];
        entry.Number = splittedValues[2];
        entry.January = splittedValues[3];
        entry.February = splittedValues[4];
        entry.March = splittedValues[5];
        entry.April = splittedValues[6];
        entry.Mai = splittedValues[7];
        entry.Juni = splittedValues[8];
        entry.Juli = splittedValues[9];
        entry.August = splittedValues[10];
        entry.September = splittedValues[11];
        entry.October = splittedValues[12];
        entry.November = splittedValues[13];
        entry.December = splittedValues[14];

        result.Entries.Add(entry);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You get this exception if you use a variable a second time. Update your code in your question, please.

Comment: My code has been updated :) Can you show me how to take instance of object :)

Comment: I don't know if you initialized the two lists in the constructor, but i think you did it. What is the problem now?

Comment: How can I create a objects for my two lists ?

Comment: this.resultYears = new List<string>();

Comment: Can you help me, I update my question

Comment: If my answers helped you, it would be nice to accept my answer :)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, we had a celebration today is my first day :)
During the weekend I tried the code, but I must say that the second file is arranged in a slightly different way, and the second combobox with the years would not be filled (filled only with last year and not all). Now I will try to fix and I will update my code with the new code and the second file :)

Comment: Can you check here :)

Comment: Did my Repsonse help you?

Comment: Yes, Hank Thank you so much ...

Comment: If my answers helped you, it would be nice to accept my answer :)